# Subsites are not visible though the "Hide subsites and workspaces" is unchecked and the user has access rights

Tags: hide, harmon.ie

Our users have access to certain subsites, and they can add the address of these subsites in Harmon.ie and navigate inside. Also, all checkboxes "Hide subsites with limited or no access" are unchecked. Therefore, we would expect that when adding the address of the "higher level" site in Harmon.ie, that we would visualise the names of the subsites below: but we don't. What can it be?

Comment: Please add more tags related to question

Answer (score 0):

Please read carefully our KB at http://harmon.ie/KB/sharepointrequirements  Browsing subsites, it details the needed permission when working through web services like Harmon.ie.
If it does not help please  re-do the security, but for on individual (for the concerned users), check whether one of the permissions didn't have the Browse Directories enabled.

We have, however, seen few situations in the past, where despite all the proper settings, such as ‘Browse Directories’, people were unable to see sub-sites or directories. Unfortunately, we were never able to reproduce such a situation inside our Labs to properly analyze that. We believe that it may be related to precedence of security settings applied to SharePoint user account. For instance, if there is a ‘Read’ and ‘Manage’ access levels – it may be that one of those has ‘Browse Directory’ while the other one doesn’t.
In the few situations that we have come across where similar issue occurred – it was resolved some times by remove the ‘Browse Directories’ setting and then applying it again.

---- Jean